# Is it possible to return updated result after updateMulti with Spring mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I'm trying to update the list of documents in MongoDB using spring template.

Smth like this:

`mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, updateDefinition, MyClass.class)`

But the result of this operation is UpdateResult, and it includes only count of updated elements.

Is it possible to return updated result like documents or java classes?

Answer (score 0):

Queries return cursors which is the thing that permits iteration over large result sets.

Writes do not return cursors.

With that I don't see how you would be able to retrieve an arbitrarily large set of documents in a result of a write command.